# Create a combined bar/line chart with dimplejs and use self-defined colors

Tags: dimple.js

I'm trying to create a combined bar/line chart based on a simple data set (columns: countries, index1, index2, index3, ...) using dimplejs. Index1 will be the bar chart and index2 upwards should be dynamically (=adding and removing indices per user interaction) displayed as line charts on top.

I found out that I seemingly needed to create a hidden 2nd x-axis for the line graphics. Is there any other way?

I was also unable to add more than one index as line chart. Is there a way to add more lines where each one is based on a column (index2, index3, ...)?

Defining colors was another problem: The bars are all in one color which is good but if I want to assign a color myself I have to give the data a tag which is displayed in the tooltip (not good)?

Assigning colors to the line charts didn't work at all for me. I would need some advice here.

My code so far:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#graphic", 550, 700);
// Get data for one year
var filteredData = dimple.filterData(data, 'year', '2010');

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, filteredData);
myChart.setBounds(50, 30, 480, 630);

var xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis('x', 'index1');
xAxis.title = 'Index Value';
xAxis.overrideMax = 1;

var yAxis = myChart.addCategoryAxis('y', 'countries');
yAxis.title = 'Country';

var xAxis2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis('x', 'index2');
xAxis2.title = null;
xAxis2.overrideMax = 1;
xAxis2.hidden = true;

var bars = myChart.addSeries('bars', dimple.plot.bar, [xAxis,yAxis]);
myChart.assignColor('bars', '#D3D3D3', '#D3D3D3');

var lines = myChart.addSeries('index2', dimple.plot.line, [xAxis2,yAxis]);

yAxis.addOrderRule('index1', false);
myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data structure is not ideal for your data requirement within dimple.  The way dimple would like that data is with your index names as dimension values:

```
var data = [
    { "Index" : "Index 1", "Country" : "UK", "Index Value": 0.2 },
    { "Index" : "Index 1", "Country" : "Spain", "Index Value": 0.7 },
    { "Index" : "Index 2", "Country" : "UK", "Index Value": 0.5 },
    { "Index" : "Index 2", "Country" : "Spain", "Index Value": 0.6 },
    { "Index" : "Index 3", "Country" : "UK", "Index Value": 0.4 },
    { "Index" : "Index 3", "Country" : "Spain", "Index Value": 0.3 },
    ...
];
```

Then in order to draw index 1 as a bar and the rest as lines you would need to split your data set into 2:

```
var barData = [],
    lineData = [],
    i,
    keyIndex = "Index 1";

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    if (data[i]["Index"] === keyIndex) {
        barData.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        lineData.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

You could then just define your chart as follows:

```
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg),
    bars,
    lines;

chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Index Value");
chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Country");

bars = chart.addSeries("Index", dimple.plot.bar);
bars.data = barData;

lines = chart.addSeries("Index", dimple.plot.line);
lines.data = lineData;

chart.draw();
```

I haven't tested this code but it ought to do what you want (minus the formatting etc).

If you want to continue on the road you have started in your code above (which is still possible) you will find composite axes very helpful to avoid hidden secondary axes and potential problems with differing max/min values.  See the relevant section in the [version 2 release notes](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/releases/tag/2.0.0) for an example of these.

I don't understand why you don't want to tag the indices with something which appears in the tooltip, there must be some difference between them which you can communicate, but if you want to remove the index name from the tooltip you can define custom tooltips as shown [here](http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_custom_tooltips).

Edit: I should add if you just want to change the set of colours which dimple will arbitrarily ascribe to your data points you can override the default colours in the chart object as discussed [here](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#defaultColors).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question that thoroughly! You are right – My main problem was the data structure. Using your solution works perfectly fine. Since I'm new to stackoverflow I'm not sure if I should ask follow-up questions in this topic or create a new one. One thing I still have a problem with is the handling of missing values. Do you have any advice in this regard?

Comment: You're welcome, it may be worth framing that in a separate question so you can give some more specifics of how it currently behaves and how you would like it to behave.

Comment: OK, the problem with missing values got solved by the new data structure. Since every data array item represents one data value, I can simply remove the elements with missing values.

Comment: But 2 follow-up questions popped up which are based on the code you provided: 1) I have another field in my data called "Disaggregation". It represents another data split which I want to display in the tooltips but it shouldn't have any impact on the chart otherwise. Do I need to add a "fake" axis for that? 2) I want to dynamically sort the y-axis (Countries) by the different indices I have. I use "yAxis.addOrderRule('Index Value', false);" which sorts by the bars. This is initially fine but how do I sort by the other indices represented as lines?

Comment: On your first point you pass it into the first parameter of the addSeries method `chart.addSeries(["Disaggregation", "Index Value"], dimple.plot.line);` If your disaggregation value differs by y value this won't work. You could cheat by drawing a bubble series over the top of the line. If you need further help please ask a new question with some example code (and preferably a jsFiddle) and I'll put a fuller answer.  The second point is a bit tricky, you might be able to do something by passing a function to the order rule but again a question with a jsFiddle would help.

Comment: I posted a [folluw-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536317/how-to-sort-y-axis-by-different-data-rows-with-dimple-js). I could solve my problem with the Disaggregations by creating a combined "Identifier" field from "Index" and "Disaggregation". Now I display the data by the Identifier field. The sorting problem is still present though. :)